Supremum of $|f'(0)|$ for analytic function on the unit disk
nLet $D= \{ z\mid |z|<1\}$ and $H=\{z\mid \text{Im }g(z)>0\}$. The  value of $$\sup \left\{ |f’(0)|\mid \text{ $f$ is an analytic function from $D$ to $H$ and $f(0)=\frac{i}{2}$} \right\}$$ is
$a$. $\frac{1}{2}$
$b$. $\frac{1}{4}$
$c$. $1$
$d$. $100$
I tried it by taking the function $f(z)= \frac{\frac{-iz}{2}-\frac{i}{2}}{z-1}$. As $|f’(0)|=1$ it seems that third option is correct option. But I tried a particular function only . Please advise. Thank you.

A common technique is to apply the Schwarz Lemma to $g = T \circ f$ where $T$ is a suitable transformation from the upper halfplane to the unit disk.

@MartinR but i will given sup | g| as 1. How about $f$? Thank you

@MartinR I edit the answer.

I take $g(z)= e^{i\theta}\frac{f(z)-\frac{i}{2}}{f(z)+\frac{i}{2}}$.

@MartinR Thank you sir
